# Python curses: module function vs instance function

Tags: python, function, module, attributes, curses

I've recently been looking into how Curses works in Python. I've followed the tutorial here: [Curses Programming with Python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), and I have successfully messed around with their code to properly output text to various locations in a console screen.

My question is:
Why are some functions attributes of the module, e.g. `curses.noecho()`
but other functions are attributes of a screen object, e.g. `sreen_instance.keypad(True)`?

It would make sense to me to have the screen instance specify things like `noecho()` or `cbreak()`, rather than the module.

What is the reasoning behind this, and is there any general rule to recognize whether a function should be an attribute of the module, or an attribute of an instance of an object within the Curses library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding the name "stdscr" as "standard **screen**", that is a curses ***window*** (and it is the top-level window in case there are subwindows).

The attributes are at the *curses*-level or *window*-level because that's how the corresponding functions are organized in curses.  Most of the Python binding has the same name and similar parameters to the C library (allowing for optional parameters in the Python binding which reduce the number of names used, e.g., for [`addstr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.addstr) in Python versus [`waddstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html) in C).

To see how that works, I'd simply look at the curses C interfaces: anything that uses a **`WINDOW*`** parameter (counting aliases such as `getch()` as [`wgetch(stdscr)`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters)) would be implemented in the Python binding as a *window* attribute (or function), while those that do not use a **`WINDOW`** parameter would be a *curses* attribute (or function).